# Setting imageview in android

Tags: java, android, xml, json, android-layout

I have a JSON URL :: `http://54.218.73.244:7006/DescriptionSortedRating/`

**JSON STRUCT**::

```
"restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 4,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney1",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "MarkBoulevard1.jpg",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 15,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Indian",
      "restaurantRATING": 1,
      "restaurantPrice": 11,
      "restaurantTime": "9am t0 8pm"
    },
```

**RestaurantDescPhotos.java**

```
public class RestaurantDescPhotos extends Activity {
    // url to make request

    private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:7006/DescriptionSortedRating/";

    String restaurant_name, cc_res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray first_array;
    TextView textView;
    TextView text;

    private SparseArray<String> imagesMap = new SparseArray<String>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_of_images = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_desc_photos);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RestaurantDescPhotos.this);
        new ParsingAsync().execute();
    }

    private class ParsingAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(RestaurantDescPhotos.this, "",
                    "Please Wait", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String _response = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
                        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);



                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                _response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(_response);
                first_array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // TextView timedisplay=(TextView)
            // findViewById(R.id.RestaurantTimeID);

            for (int i = 0; i < first_array.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject detail_obj = first_array.getJSONObject(i);

                    HashMap<String, String> map_for_images = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    int id = detail_obj.getInt("_id");
                    String IMAGES = detail_obj.getString("restaurantIMAGE");

                    map_for_images.put("Starters", IMAGES);

                    list_of_images.add(map_for_images);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DISP_IMG);


        }
    }
}
```

**RestaurantDescPhotos.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2sp" >
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/DescriptionTitleRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="2sp" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/DISP_IMG"
                            android:layout_width="167dp"
                            android:layout_height="167dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

- I have a imageview in XML
- How to set the image view for the JSONURL
- I have coded some part of the class but trying to know how to set the
  imageview

**Any ideas**

Comment: Check Picasso library.

Comment: Hey see the updated question .... i am using a image loader .... i just want to know how to set the imageview using it ... any ideas ........ Note - I already have utils.java, memorycache.java & others required for image]

Comment: ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(yourImageView,imageUrl);

Comment: I got the idea but there are more problems .... ill make a new questions with proper explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your Image using ImageLoader...

Create instance of ImageLoader globally like..

```
  ImageLoader imageLoader;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ......
           imageLoader=new  ImageLoader(ClassName.this);


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DISP_IMG);
           ......
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(YourImageURLHere,imageView);
```

Comment: I got the idea but there are more problems .... ill make a new questions with proper explanation

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. Download AndroidQuery jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar).
2. Put this jar to your libs folder and right click on jar and Build Path -> Add to bulid path
3. How to use see this example

   ```
   AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this); // make AndroidQuery object 

   androidQuery.id(yourImageView).image(imageUrl, isCacheUrlImageOnMemery, isCacheUrlImageOnFile); //  use this way 

   isCacheUrlImageOnMemery - if true then given url image cahce on memery so after word android query check is given url image cahce on either memery or file then it take from cahce other wise it try to getting from url 

   isCacheUrlImageOnFile - same like isCacheUrlImageOnMemery but first of all android query check on memery then file in case if we have not much of memery then we cahce on file tht y two option are available.
   ```

Comment: Hey see the updated question .... i am using a image loader .... i just want to know how to set the imageview using it ... any ideas .... [Note - I already have utils.java, memorycache.java & others required for image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library to load your image from URL:
https://github.com/shaunidiot/AndroidTutorial/tree/master/ionimagetest/bin

refer to this tutorial video of how to do it:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwR44n54-bk

This library will do all the asyncTask process to load and view the image and you can also use placeholder image if the image from the URL is deleted or not available