# How to store image in my imageview from the parse table that i import from the .json file

Tags: android, parsing

i import my jeson file in parse.com import section this file contain image, i want to store this image in my image view using base adapter, i not have any idea about image so please help me, for string we do following,

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("insatall");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {

                String name = (String) objectList.get(i).get("name");
                String address = (String) objectList.get(i).get("address");

                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put(NAME, name);
                item.put(ADDRESS, address);
                arraylist.add(item);

            }
            lvAdapter = new BaseAdapter2(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            list.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
        }
    }
});
```

and in my base adapter in getview method:

```
         holder.named.setText(arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.NAME));
         holder.address.setText(arraylist.get(position)
            .get(MainActivity.ADDRESS));
```

how i do for image for exact above in both mainActivity and baseAdapter please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: have you know about "AndroidQuery" lib which can be provide best way to load image from url...

Comment: no i have no idea about it

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086192/setting-imageview-in-android/19086298#19086298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image loader and put following code in your main activity's query.findInBackground(..) method :

```
     if (objectList.get(i).getParseFile("image") == null) {
               System.out.println("image       default");
               item.put(IMAGEKEY,"defaultImage.jpg");
         } 
         else 
         {
           item.put(IMAGEKEY,objectList.get(i).getParseFile("image").getUrl());
         }

     }
```

and in your base adapter Constructor define :

```
          ImageLoader imgLoader;   //     top part         
          imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);  // in constructors
```

and in yout getview methods :

```
     Uri uri=Uri.parse(arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.IMAGEKEY));
     String stringUri;
     stringUri = uri.toString();
     imgLoader.DisplayImage(stringUri,R.drawable.ic_launcher,holder.image);
```

and include necessary java files for imageLoader your work done.
i hope this helpful to you.

Comment: thanks yaar it very much useful for me,i load image successfully thanks again.