# add bitmap image in listview in android

Tags: android, bitmapimage

Can you suggest me any tutorial that how to add bitmap in listview. I got an image from json data and need to put that in listView.Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Check out this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086192/setting-imageview-in-android/19086298#19086298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this tutorial 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

If you want to show image in your list view, add image component in your list_view_row_item and set image in your adapter.

Comment: first of all thanks for your replay. Actually I am getting images from json and i converted them into bitmap.I wanted to show that bitmap image in listView. I have seen the above link which you have given.I that link they have shown static images in listview.But for me it should be dynamic

Comment: Take an array of Bitmap and pass it to the adapter you created. In the get view method simply set the bitmap to the imageview

Comment: @Shink can you give me any example..or any link.Because I don't know the procudure.Thanks

Comment: have a look at this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/

Comment: thanks worked out.got an exact output...:)